# Clear localStorage on logout

Tags: javascript, laravel, local-storage, storage, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel and I set an item in localStorage(), but I want to clear it when that user is not logged in anymore.
How can I do this?

Can I access local storage in Controller?

Let me know if you need anything from me to find the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete local storage items of browser on logout using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739148/how-to-delete-local-storage-items-of-browser-on-logout-using-php)

Comment: Yes thank you I can work with that. But I have another question. What happens when the authentication session expires does local storage get cleared?

Comment: No. You will have to handle that I guess. Is the authentication session expiry check client side or server side?

Comment: Can you try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993238/4008454

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear local storage using JavaScript, then you can use code shown in below.

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

When you invoke the above method, that clear entire storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> `onclick="localStorage.clear();"`

in your anchor tag

like this

> 

```
<a href="{{ route('nova.logout') }}" onclick="localStorage.clear();" class="block no-underline text-90 hover:bg-30 p-3">
     {{ __('Logout') }}
</a>
```